# WCF - communication between two methods

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, c#-4.0

I have a WCF client, that asks for order confirmation and WCF service with two methods:

1) UpdateOrder - updates order data in database (UpdateOrder call comes from external service)
2) GetConfirmationResult - which holds return of result till order status will change from pending to something else.

Question is, how to make notification from UpdateOrder to GetConfirmationResult, that order status has changed, in WCF?

Update: would be best, if I could leave InstanceContextMode as Per-Call.

Update 2: Let's say possible order statuses are Pending, Confirmed, Rejected. ConfirmOrder may change order status to Confirmed or Rejected, GetConfirmationResult should not return result until it is changed by Confirm order.

Update 3: I've changed image with sequence to display whole stack.

[image]

Comment: Is your confirm order method one way? What transport are you using?

Comment: @hugh: confirm order method is one way, transport is https.

Comment: Also, is your client for GetConfirmationResult call on the same network as your service?

Comment: From left to right: asp.net mvc application, wcf application, external service. asp.net mvc application and wcf application are on same network (ec2), external service is on different network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment I've solved it using EventWaitHandle - not sure if it is the best way, but it looks quite clean, nicely supports timeout and is quite testable.

```
public class TestClass 
{
    public static event OrderUpdateHandler UpdatedOrder;

    public void UpdateData(Order order) 
    {
        // ...

        OnOrderUpdated(args);
    }

    public Order GetConfirmedOrder(int id, TimeSpan waitToConfirm) 
    {
        var order = GetOrderFromDatabase();

        if (order.Status == OrderStatus.Pending) 
        {
             var eventHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);

             UpdatedOrderHandler waiter = (s, e) =>
             {
                if (e.Order.Id == id)
                {
                    order = e.Order;
                    eventHandle.Set();
                }
            };

            UpdatedOrder += waiter;

            if (!eventHandle.WaitOne(waitToConfirm))
            {                
                return order;
            }

            OrderUpdated -= waiter;
        }

        return order;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one! If this is your solution please mark as answer. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You say you have a database backing this server. Then it'll be as simple as this, semi-psuedo:

```
public YourService : YourServiceInterface
{
    public void UpdateOrder(Order order)
    {
        using (context = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            context.Orders.Where(o => o.ID == order.ID).First().IsConfirmed = order.IsConfirmed;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public Boolean? GetConfirmationResult(Order order)
    {
        using (context = new DatabaseContext())
        {
            return context.Orders.Where(o => o.ID == order.ID).First().IsConfirmed;
        }
    }   
}
```

You'll have to persist it, since you're mentioning a per call instance mode. You can't keep a `static List<Order>` to contain your pending orders, simply persist them to your database and add them as pending, not approved.

Comment: I've mentioned, that GetConfirmationResult holds result until the moment order status changes from pending to something else, so in your solution if I query GetConfirmationResult and ConfirmOrder hasn't updated order yet, it will return result, though it should not. I've updated question to make this more clear.

Comment: @Giedrius I don't know what you mean by _"it will return result, though it should not"_. What do you want it to do when an order is not confirmed yet? In my case it returns `false`.

Comment: Thread.Sleep I guess :) Thing is, that result is needed for web application, so there are several solutions - we may repeat requests to wcf until we get result which indicates confirmation happened or we can delay issuing of a result on wcf side.

Comment: @Giedrius I still would prefer returning `null` or `false` in that case, otherwise you'll hit timeouts and whatnot. Make the client poll every N minutes, until the order is confirmed.

Comment: In my opinion holding result on wcf side would be faster/require less data traffic, as long as confirmation has no human intervention, it is matter of seconds, not minutes. Thing is, that client is waiting for confirmation looking at the screen, so time is important.

Comment: @Giedrius you could of course simply put a Thread.Sleep in there, perhaps even in a loop, but then your service will be pounding the database until an order has changed, while still risking transport timeouts. Polling is much more common.

Comment: So that is the question - if UpdateOrder would produce notice to GetConfirmationResult, I would not require to pound database. Transport timeouts would be handled in a way, that if GetConfirmationResult does not get notice from UpdateOrder in N seconds, it is almost exception and is handled in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your problem is based on the fact that the order state changes at certain times and only when that stage change happens is it relevant for the service consumer to know about the new order state.

This is a perfect scenario for using messaging.

Rather than your wcf client calling the service, the service should just send a message to the client when the state of the order changes. The client can then process the message (in your case a ConfirmationResult message).

You can do this by using the netMsmqBinding and host an operation on the client which accepts a msmq message.

```
[OperationContract]
void ReceiveConfirmationResult(ConfirmationResult result);
```

This is far simpler as it removes the source of your problem entirely. As an added benefit the service operation GetConfirmationResult() can be removed as it is no longer needed.

**UPDATE**

I think you misunderstand because based on your latest question update this is an even stronger case for using queueing.

Order of events:

1. Order confirmation received
2. The server state changes
3. The server applies logic to work out if a state change should be sent to the clients
4. The Server sends a message to the client describing the state change

Comment: I completely agree with you, but still don't understand why to try avoid long polling (or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming))

Comment: Because it's complex. Queueing is really, really simple. Additionally you gain other benefits such as availability and durability. If you had to go over the internet then I would agree that comet or some other long polling strategy would be the best way.

Comment: I've done some thinking and I think that using messaging in my case would only move the problem from WCF application to client (ASP.NET MVC) application, I'll try to update my question to show why it is so.

Comment: If answer is queuing, question is how do I bind ReceiveConfirmationResult with action? If you'll take a look at updated sequence image, javascript is calling MVC action and that action returns html as a result, so at the moment I don't see how to implement asp.net mvc part without moving problem from WCF to asp.net mvc, may be you could write pseudocode or give existing example?

Comment: I see what you mean now about "moving the problem" from wcf to mvc. However, browser push is a long standing problem which has been solved in many different ways. It is more appropriate to address it there. http://blog.programmableweb.com/2011/02/25/the-evolution-and-future-of-real-time-browser-push/